# Problem with font size depending on screen resolution - QT

Tags: qgis-plugins, resolution, pyqt, qt, qt-designer

I developed a QGIS plugin by designing the interface with QT Designer.

The inferface appears correctly on my computer (left image).

However, on some computers, I encounter size problems, especially font size (right image).

I noticed that the problem was encountered when in the windows settings "scaling and layout", the variable
"change the size of text, applications and other items" was set to 125% instead of 100% on my computer.

[image]

I have read a few things about the use of layout and the declaration of the environment variable QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR =1.

Is there a trick to avoid this kind of problem?

Comment: I haven't used Qt but this might answer your question: https://www.charlesodale.com/setting-qt-to-ignore-windows-dpi-text-size-personalization/. EDIT: Just reread the link i posted. It seems that the best solution is mentioned in the comments of the blogpost. Running `QApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_Use96Dpi);` before instantiating your QApplication object should be the best solution

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I didn't try it, but I'd read that trick. Maybe the interface will appear correctly at runtime but in QT Designer it will not appear correctly. I'll try what you edited.

Comment: Sorry for the double comment. I still have the problem.